# How to monitor Ethernet connection status

Tags: c#, networking, ethernet

How can I monitor if Ethernet cables are plugged in or not from .NET for a given Ethernet connection?

I would like to enumerate all Ethernet connections and subscribe to any connection status changes. I am not interested in detecting Internet access, only if an Ethernet connection is *Connected* or *Not Connected*.

**Update:** I found [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/21/how-can-i-be-notified-any-time-a-network-cable-gets-unplugged.aspx) on how to use a WMI query to be notified of disconnections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `NetConnectionStatus` property of the [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class.

Comment: I ended up using WMI to subscribe to disconnect notifications.